# Connecting VSCode to PostgreSQL databases created through psql on Ubuntu using PostgresSQL extension

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Problem with connecting to databases through PostgreSQL extension on VSCode

I have a question regarding PostgreSQL. I want to connect my VScode to databases that I created using PostgresSQL on my computer. I tried using PostgreSQL extension on VSCode, but I wasn't able to connect. I guess I'm missing something. I created databases through psql on Ubuntu, but when I try to make a connection on VSCode, nothings happens.. Does anybody have a suggestion ?

Comment: Did you try to open the connection, or did you just define without doing anything with it?

Comment: I tried to establish (make) a new connection as this is the first time I'm using the extension. So, I tried to connect to one of the existing db that I had created on bash. The problem is, it doesn't give me any error but it doesn't connect neither. In the 6th step when I choose the standard connection, rather than secure, it just tries to connect but nothing happens. I used postgres as a username without any password, and port 5432

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).